# Como detectar si un usuario esta haciendo scroll hacia abajo y hacia arriba

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero poder condicionar si un usuario hace scroll hacia abajo o scroll hacia arriba, para poder mostrar el botón solo cuando esta subiendo y cuando baja con el scroll se oculte el botón. Les dejo el código.

```
<!-- código HTMl botón subir (top)-->
<a href="#" class="js-boton-subir">
 subir
</a>



<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 //BOTÓN SUBIR
  $(window).scroll(function(){

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 300){ 
      $('.js-boton-subir').slideDown(300).css('display', 'flex');
    }else{
      $('.js-boton-subir').slideUp(300);
    }
    
  });


$('.js-boton-subir').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
   $('body,html').animate({ 
     scrollTop: 0 
   },700); 
   return false;
});
</script>
```

Bueno el código es básico mi idea es cuando el usuario haga scroll hacia abajo el botón no se muestre, pero cuando el usuario haga scroll hacia arriba se muestre. Parecido a la librería [Headroom.js](https://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/playroom/), gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Actualización:

El código funciona bien, a lo que me refiero es que cuando el usuario haga scroll hacia abajo no se muestre y si hace scroll hacia arriba se muestre no importa el valor de scrollTop

Answer (score 1):

No se puede detectar si esta haciendo "scroll down" o "scroll up", por lo que, debes averiguar tu mismo si está subiendo o bajando almacenando el valor del scroll anterior, te muestro un pequeño código de ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```js
let lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
   const currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
   if (currentScroll > lastScroll){
      // scroll down
      $('#hiddenButton').removeClass().addClass('hidden');
   } else {
      // scroll up
      $('#hiddenButton').removeClass().addClass('stickyButton');
   }
   
   // scroll update
   lastScroll = currentScroll <= 0 ? 0 : currentScroll;
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.stickyButton {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  
  margin: 15px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px #ccc;
  color: #888;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <button id="hiddenButton" class="hidden">click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que hayas puesto mal las instrucciones dentro del if, te pongo el código modificado con comentarios.

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > 300){
    // Aquí el scroll está a más de 300 así que se oculta
    $('.js-boton-subir').slideUp(300);
}else{
    // Aquí el scroll está a menos de 300 así que se muestra
    $('.js-boton-subir').slideDown(300).css('display', 'flex');      
}
```